# How to apply wildcard in instr() in MySQL?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, wildcard

Using a wildcard so all records will be matched.

My code:

```
if(empty($tag))
{
$tag="%";
}

mysql_query("select * from mytable where instr(tag,'$tag')>0") or die(mysql_error());
```

But it returns zero result.
Even if

```
 if(empty($tag))
    {
    $tag="*";
    }
```

It still returns zero result. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSTR` does not support wildcards.

If you want to use wildcards in a MySQL query, you'll have to use a function that supports it, such as [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) or [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp), ie:

```
mysql_query("select * from mytable where tag LIKE '%$tag%'")
```

The above query will work for any value of `$tag`.  A blank value (empty string) will return all records.  Be sure you properly sanitize your `$tag` value as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `instr` (and its counterpart `locate`) do not recognize wildcards or any other special expression—only literal strings.  The usual way to handle this is to modify the SQL accordingly:

```
if (empty($tag))
     $whereclause = "";  // match all records
else $whereclause = "where instr(tag, '$tag') > 0";

mysql_query("select * from mytable $whereclause") or die(mysql_error());
```