# How to use case sensitivity in instr() in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, case-sensitive

**Possible duplicate:** [How to apply wildcard in instr() in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905119/how-to-apply-wildcard-in-instr-in-mysql)

The possible duplicate linked shows a query which is exactly like my current one sort of. However, I cannot find a way to make it a case **sensitive** match. :\

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE INSTR(flags, 'T') > 0;
```

I get a count of 46 which is obviously wrong. It's counting every instance "T" in flags whether it's upper- or lower-case.

It works as according to the MySQL documentation. I found something in the MySQL docs that said to put an "@" symbol on a variable to make it a case sensitive match. However, I tried this on the @'T' to form the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE INSTR(flags, @'T') > 0;
```

I get a count of zero.

Could anyone shed some light on this for me? :)

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention, sorry. I also tried a `LIKE '%T%'` as the where-clause, which still failed and returns the same as `(INSTR(flags, 'T') > 0)`;

Comment: Perhaps you could post your sample `flags` value, so we can test against it.

Comment: `flags` would be something like "TkKp" where "T" is what I'm matching. The example string where the "T" is lower-case is: "AKkRBbagSsPpCtmxeGhUX"

Comment: I'm trying to get a count of how many entries in my table have a particular field contain a "T".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested,

```
SELECT binary 'AKkRBbagSsPpCtmxeGhUX' LIKE '%T%';
```

produces '0', as expected. According to the [String Comparison](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) documentation, LIKE performs a binary (thus, case-sensitive) comparison if either of its operands are binary.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this will work

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE INSTR(binary flags, 'T') > 0;
```

Comment: Hmm. Didn't work as it returned a count of 5 which is still incorrect :(

Comment: You mentioned trying `LIKE`, have you tried `binary flags LIKE '%T%'` or maybe `binary flags LIKE binary '%T%'`.