# How to make a 'select' with case-sensitive 'like' in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, select, case-sensitive

I want to filter my columns with a `like` in `select` clause, the default `like` in MySQL is case-insensitive, but I want it to be case-sensitive. How to do it?

I want this query:

```
select * from my_table where column1 like '%abc%'
```

and this query:

```
select * from my_table where column1 like '%Abc%'
```

to give different results.

Comment: This answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036200/how-to-use-case-sensitivity-in-instr-in-mysql

Comment: maybe this can point you in the right direction... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The default character set and collation are `latin1` and `latin1_swedish_ci`, so nonbinary string comparisons are case insensitive by default. This means that if you search with `col_name LIKE 'a%'`, you get all column values that start with `A` or `a`. **To make this search case sensitive, make sure that one of the operands has a case sensitive or binary collation.** For example, if you are comparing a column and a string that both have the `latin1` character set, you can use the `COLLATE` operator to cause either operand to have the `latin1_general_cs` or `latin1_bin` collation:
>
> ```
> col_name COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE 'a%'
> col_name LIKE 'a%' COLLATE latin1_general_cs
> col_name COLLATE latin1_bin LIKE 'a%'
> col_name LIKE 'a%' COLLATE latin1_bin
> ```

[MySQL :: MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual :: C.5.5.1 Case Sensitivity in String Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case-sensitivity.html) (emphasis added)

Comment: is it possible to put something into the query to make string comparison case-sensitive?

Comment: Did you miss the part about reading the docs? ...See my edit, it's the very next sentence in the part I quoted.

Comment: Follow Matt's link to the manual.  It'll show you how to solve your problem in a variety of ways.  One simple example is to replace ['%Abc'] with ['%Abc' COLLATE latin1_bin].

Comment: but my collation is utf8_general_ci, and i have non-standard-latin characters like "Â" and "â", "Ă" and "ă", etc.

Comment: The `ci` means "case insensitive," so you need the case-sensitive version: `['%Abc' COLLATE utf8_general_cs]`.